# Count of the max value in an aggregate select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count the number of the number of the maximum value of the minimum values in a particular field.

This select is broken if I were to uncomment the lines:

```
select clientnumber
      ,count(distinct clientname) as NumberUnique
      ,max(clientname) as UniqueSample1
      -- ,sum(case clientname when min(clientname) then 1 else 0 end) as UniqueCount1
      ,min(clientname) as UniqueSample2
      -- ,sum(case clientname when min(clientname) then 1 else 0 end) as UniqueCount2
  FROM dbo.InvoicesSent dt
 group by clientnumber
 having count(distinct clientname) > 1
```

Background:
We are reviewing records that have two different names on the invoices for the same clientnumber.  Knowing which one of the two has the higher count is handy for the analysis.

Note:
I know there are other solutions that can take into account more than 2 unique values but at this point, I want to solve this problem for its academic value.  I also know I could solve this with a subselect but I am holding out for some graceful solution.

Comment: Since you can't nest aggregation functions you pretty much have to use a `CTE` or a subquery.

Comment: @Nick Yeah, you are right but I like to be surprised with what some clever person can come up with that is graceful solutions.  CTE will not be too bad I think.

Comment: "pretty recent version of sql server" is not useful.

Comment: Can you please edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: It looks like you got an answer with no subqueries which will work for 2 unique values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that there are two names, then you could do this without a subselect:

```
select top (1) with ties clientnumber, 
       min(clientname) over (partition by clientnumber) as min_name,
       max(clientname) over (partition by clientnumber) as max_name,
       (case when clientname = min(clientname) over (partition by clientnumber)
             then count(*)
             else sum(count(*)) over (partition by clientnumber) - count(*)
        end) as min_count,
       (case when clientname = max(clientname) over (partition by clientnumber)
             then count(*)
             else sum(count(*)) over (partition by clientnumber) - count(*)
        end) as max_count
from InvoicesSent i
group by clientnumber, clientname
order by row_number() over (partition by clientnumber order by clientname) +
         (case when min(clientname) over (partition by clientnumber) = max(clientname) over (partition by clientnumber) then 1 else 0 end);
```

I am not arguing that this is elegant.  Merely that it is possible for your conditions.

Here is a slightly simpler form:

```
select top (1) with ties clientnumber, 
       clientname as min_name,
       max(clientname) over (partition by clientnumber) as max_name,
       count(*) as min_count,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by clientnumber) - count(*) max_count
from InvoicesSent i
group by clientnumber, clientname
order by row_number() over (partition by clientnumber order by clientname) +
         (case when count(*) over (partition by clientnumber) >= 2 then 0 else 1 end)
```

And a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=41f46aaec0fc9a9dce1500470fa42b0d).

Actually, this isn't so bad.  It is aggregating by the name column and the client, putting all the data on one row using window functions and then selecting the one row.  There is a little trick in the `order by` to only select clients with more than one name.

Comment: This is interesting, Ugly, but interesting. I was sure that every time I'd tried to use nested aggregation (even using window functions) I'd got errors. Now I need to go back and revisit a few problems. It's a pity it won't work for more than 2 names.

Comment: @Nick . . .It might be possible to generalize it for more names, but the OP is specifically asking about two names.

Comment: yeah, I only care about 2 samples because this is an iterative clean up with a person making a decision on which name to use.  they will know to dig a little deeper when the count(*) > 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making use of sql server that supports string_agg the following can be done

Here is a db fiddble link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4184c994d37e0dc7178212cd657ba15f

```
create table invoices(id int identity, clientnumber int, clientname varchar(100));

insert into invoices(clientnumber,clientname)
select t.clientnumber,clientname
  from (values(100,'Adam')
             ,(100,'Adam')
             ,(100,'Abraham')
             ,(101,'Grace')
             ,(101,'Grace')
             ,(102,'Paul')
       )t(clientnumber,clientname);



select clientnumber
      ,string_agg(concat(clientname,'-',cnt),';') as clientname_and_cnt
 from(     
select distinct
       clientnumber
      ,clientname
      ,count(*) over(partition by clientnumber,clientname) as cnt
  from invoices
     )x
group by clientnumber     
order by 2 desc

Output
+--------------+--------------------+
| clientnumber | clientname_and_cnt |
+--------------+--------------------+
|          102 | Paul-1             |
|          101 | Grace-2            |
|          100 | Abraham-1;Adam-2   |
+--------------+--------------------+
```

And if you want to show up those which have two or more clientnames by clientnumber then
Add the following in the having clause

```
having(charindex(';',string_agg(concat(clientname,'-',cnt),';')))<>0
```

If you would like ordering based on the number of invoices by the clientname then you may also do the following (within group clause)

```
select clientnumber
      ,string_agg(concat(clientname,'-',cnt),';') within group(order by cnt desc) as clientname_and_cnt
 from(     
select distinct
       clientnumber
      ,clientname
      ,count(*) over(partition by clientnumber,clientname) as cnt
  from invoices
     )x
group by clientnumber     
order by 2 desc
```